# How to get method for class in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, class

I have a class:

```
class myObject: NSObject {
    dynamic var objectId : String?
    dynamic var name : String?
    dynamic var lastName : String?
    dynamic var age : String? 
}
```

In my other class I am getting the value of this class's property:

```
self.myArray.append(myObject.name!)
```

I can get the value of `myObject.name` by adding `.name` but what if there will be hundreds of properties in my `myObject` class? For that I want to create a method which can return the properties of my class using a variable:

```
let myVar = "name"
self.myArray.append(myObject.myVar)
```

It should append the values of property `name`, but I am getting an error:

```
value of myObject has no member `myVar`
```

and I know why I am getting the error.

How can I get access to properties  of my class using a variable? Something like `:getValue(String)` should return that property of my class.

Answer (score 1):

You should also have a look at `NSMutableDictionary`, here's a quick example which shows how it works

```
// initialise a dictionary
var dict = NSMutableDictionary(objects: ["first", "second", 42], forKeys: ["String1", "String2", "Int1"])

// add a new attribute                
dict.addEntriesFromDictionary(NSDictionary(object: "New thing", forKey: "String3") as [NSObject : AnyObject])

// access the data
let firstString = dict.valueForKey("String1")
let firstInt = dict.valueForKey("Int1")

// update the data
dict.setValue(99, forKey: "Int1")

let newValue = dict.valueForKey("Int1")
```

Comment: hey @russell thanks  for responding man , i think am failed to describe what i actually want in my question  and i came up with this `myArray.append(obj.valueForKey("\(myVar)") as! String)` and its doing exactly what i want anyways thanks for your efforts i really appreciate this

Comment: @remyboys I don't think it's a good idea to do so in swift, just because it's Objective-C feature, called KVC and is available just because your class is a subclass of NSObject (that is Objective-C class). imo Russel is right, it's not a good idea to keep hundreds of properties in your class and it's better to use dictionaries

Comment: @AntonTyutin so what should i should for making it right ? any idea ? if yes then please guide me

Answer (score 1):

I can be wrong, but as I've already said in a comment, it would be better to use Dictionary and store values in it. Also if you want to access some values with a dot-notation, but still be able to get them by string, you can just create a property and override setter and getter

```
class MyClass {
    var properties = [String: AnyObject]()

    var someProperty: String? {
        get {
            return properties["someProperty"] as? String
        }
        set {
            properties["someProperty"] = newValue
        }
}
```

This way you are able to access value of someProperty both by `object.someProperty` and `object.properties["someProperty"]`

Comment: okay let me try this , because my class is going to also linked with backendless (an  Mbbas ) so i am not sure what will but let me check  this out and thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it making array of object like following

```
var arrayOfObjects = [myObject]
```

and then set an objects values

```
var firstObject:myObject
myObject.name = "Your name"
myObject.age = "Your age"
...
```

then append first object to arrayOfObjects

```
arrayOfObject.append(firstObject)
```

and you can access it

```
print("First Object's name: \(arrayOfObjects[0].name)")
```

Comment: hey brother thanks for responding ,  can you please elaborate your answer a little bit i'm not getting it

Comment: The way you handle multiple object in swift is you loop through them and sets them for example in table view controller you sets the data of each cell through array elements and then afterwards you get the data by index path.

Comment: oh okay but actually values are already there i just want to access the  property  and i used this `myArray.append(obj.valueForKey("\(myVar)") as! String)`  but thanks a lot for your efforts, i appreciate this